# Is TTL (Time To live) in the IP packet in seconds or steps?

Tags: dns, ip, ttl, nameservers

From my previous knowledge, I know that TTL is the amount of routing steps an IP packet is allowed to travel.

On DNS, we are using a IP/UDP base, and from the documentation I see that the TTL actually means the amount of seconds the data stays in the cache of the NameServer.

Am I missing something or is it both?

Thanks

Comment: Two different 'TTL's.

Comment: As Andrew Barber told, 'TTL' has [two representative meanings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP TTL is in steps.  Time limits, caching, and the like take place at higher levels of the [protocol stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model); IP doesn't know or care about them.